# How to find curves of intersection between two surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

The curve of the intersection of the surface $x^2+y^2-2z^2=1$ and the plane $y=2z+1$ is given by $\varphi(t)=(\sqrt2\cos t,2\sin t-1,\sin t-1), t\in [0,2\pi)$.

I would like to know how to find it if I didn't know the answer. I've already tried to make projections and substitutions ($z=t$) without success.

Does anyone know a good other method to find curves of intersection of surfaces?

Answer (score 1):

From the two equations we have:

$$x^2+(2z+1)^2-2z^2=1$$

$$x^2+2z^2+4z=0$$

$$x^2+2(z+1)^2=2$$

$$x=\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{1-(z+1)^2}$$

Its only natural to set $(z+1)$ as $\sin(t)$ or $\cos(t)$, from which the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $y=2z+1$ in the first equation you get $x^2+2z^2+4z=0$, which by completing the squares reduces to
$$ \frac{x^2}{2} +(z+1)^2=1 $$
Now you can recognize the equation of an ellipse in the $xz$ plane centered in $(0,0,-1)$ and axes $\sqrt{2}$ and $1$, which can be parametrized by $(\sqrt{2}\cos t, 0, -1+\sin t)$ in the $xz$ plane. Now thinking this equation in three dimension, we are dealing with a cylinder whose axis is parallel to the $y$-axis and we have to intersect it with the plane of equation $y=2z+1$, which gives us $y=-2+2\sin t+1=2\sin t-1$ as we wanted.